# remove() or clear() from SharedPreferences not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to clean my Arraylist with SharedPreferences, but the code below isn't working:

```
public void btnLimparPref(View v){

         SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("listaPedidos", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
         preferences.edit().clear().commit();
     }
```

This code is an Activity and the Arraylist is saved in a Fragment, by this code:

```
void criaArray(String nomeProd, String descrProd) {


        HashMap<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<String, String>();           
        map3.put(TAG_NM, nomeProd);
        map3.put(TAG_DS, descrProd);

        listaPedidos.add(map3);    

            //getListView();
            ((BaseAdapter) adapter2).notifyDataSetChanged();

            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            try {
                editor.putString("listaPedidos", ObjectSerializer.serialize(listaPedidos));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            editor.commit();

    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using two different `SharedPreferences` objects in your two code snippets.

In the first, you are using:

```
getSharedPreferences("listaPedidos", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE)`
```

In the second, you are using:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
```

Changes you make to one of those have no effect on the other.

Also, in the future, when you ask questions on Stack Overflow, please provide a **complete** explanation of what "isn't working" means.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about that, I thought saying methods remove() or clear() and not working could explain my problem, thought it was clearly visible what was happening! I've understand your point, but, can you show for me how can I use the same on both, Commonsware?

Comment: @xxxxxx: "how can I use the same on both" -- ummm, just replace one with the other. All else being equal, I would recommend that you use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`.

Comment: Hahaha, sorry and thanks, it worked! I don't know but the code I've did it's removing without hitting the button that I've wrote the code. Every time I start the app and goes to the activity, it removes the data storaged. May I add a listener for this or something? I want to remove when the button is pressed..

Comment: @xxxxxx: Well, I don't know what your activity looks like and where you are using any of the code that you have changed from what you posted. Please consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, where you show your current code, including all relevant pieces of the activity (e.g., `onCreate()`).